# About Virtual function, errors

Tags: c++

I want to create a shape class to draw rectangles and circles in Oxy and out of the area.
I have to use virtual function, and it goes to errors:

> 43    10  D:\Cpp\TurboC4\OOPCpp\shape.cpp [Error] cannot declare field 'Circle::r' to be of abstract type 'Shape'
>   6   7   D:\Cpp\TurboC4\OOPCpp\shape.cpp   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Shape':
>   18  18  D:\Cpp\TurboC4\OOPCpp\shape.cpp     virtual float Shape::area()

Here's my code:

```
class Shape{
    public:
            int x,y;
    public:
            void set_data (int a,int b){
                x=a;
                y=b;
            }
            void input(){
                cout<<"x= "; cin>>x;
                cout<<"y= "; cin>>y;
            }
            virtual float area()=0;

};

class Rectangle: public Shape{

    public:
            Rectangle(){
                x=0;
                y=0;
            }
            Rectangle(int x,int y){
                this->x=x;
                this->y=y;
            }
            void input(){
                cout<<"Enter value of width and height: ";
                cin>>x;
                cin>>y;
            }
            float area(){
                return x*y;
            }
};

class Circle: public Shape{
    protected:
            Shape r;
    public:
            Circle(){
                r.x=0;
                r.y=0;

            }
            //center of Circle: default(0,0) , r is 1 point in the circle.
            Circle(int x,int y){
                r.x=x;
                r.y=y;
            }   
            void nhap(){
                        cout<<"Enter values x,y of r: ";
                        cin>>x;
                        cin>>y;
            }
            virtual float area(){
                float a=sqrt(r.x*r.x+r.y*r.y);
                return 3.14*a*a;
            }
};

class ArrayOfShape{
    private:
            int n;
            Shape **a;
    public:
            void nhap(){
                int hinh;
                cout<<"input number of shape: ";
                cin>>n;
                a=new Shape*[n];
                for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    cout<<"\nEnter shape (1:rectangle,2:circle): ";
                    cin>>hinh;
                    if (hinh==1){
                        Rectangle *p=new Rectangle();
                        p->nhap();
                        a[i]=p;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(hinh==2){
                        Circle *e=new Circle();
                        e->input();
                        a[i]=e;
                        }
                        else{
                            cout<<"Invilid input";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            void area(){
                for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
                cout<<"\nArea of shape"<<i+1<<" : "<<a[i]->area();
            }
};

int main(){
    ArrayOfShape a;
    a.input();
    a.area();
}
```

Comment: Object abstract class not allowed in c++.

Comment: your problem is when you try to add protected member of `Circle` as in `Shape r`. This cannot be since `Shape` is abstract class.

Comment: Shape is a abstract class and you try to create abstract class object in Circle class.

Comment: I would expect `r` to be the radius of the circle, not a `Shape` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your helps! Understood

Comment: @Asilenceriver don't forget to accept one of the answers (green tick on the left) to award a reputation bonus and mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the member variable `r` in `Circle`, then you declare an *instance* of the `Shape` class. Since `Shape` is an abstract class, that is not possible.

You need to make the variable `r` either a reference or a pointer.

---

After reading your code a little more, you probably should not use a member variable here at all, but use the `x` and `y` members you *inherit* from the `Shape` base class. Like you already do in the `Rectangle` class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
class Circle: public Shape{
    protected:
            Shape r; // Wrong
```

Because Shape is a pure virtual function, you cannot create an instance of it (which is precisely what `Shape r` tries to do).

Possible solution:

```
class Circle: public Shape{
protected:
    int x, y
    ...
    public Circle() {
      x = y = 0;  // Do you really need "r" at all?  Why not just x and y?
      ...
```

ALSO:

If you're really using Turbo C++ ... please don't.  It's 20 years out of date ... and it matters.  Especially if you're learning.  There are plenty of free and/or Open Source C++ compilers that would probably serve you much better...

Comment: Ah, I just want to see "r" cause it seems so pro. :) I don't know, maybe :3 sorry about my complex. Thank you ! I will clear it! 
my English is not good!